# Apex 22.1 Session Sharing with Custom Authentication Scheme

Tags: oracle-apex

I have configured two of my apps with Custom authentication which is working fine. Now I want to share Session between these two apps.

Session sharing type `Workspace Sharing` works fine with Scheme Type `Oracle APEX Accounts`, tested it with two different apps.

But Session sharing type `Workspace Sharing` is not working with Scheme Type `Custom` and page is directed to login page.

Further, if Session sharing type is changed from `Workspace Sharing` to `Custom` and Cookie Name is set to abcdxyz then following error occurs on switching to other app

```
You are not authorized to view this application, either because you have not been granted access, or your account has been locked. Please contact the application administrator.
Access denied by Application security check

Technical Info (only visible for developers)
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: APEX.AUTHORIZATION.ACCESS_DENIED
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_AUTHORIZATION
component.id: 2039750985300660
component.name: Reader Rights
```

I am also setting some items on Global page in my custom authentication function of the first app. How would those items be accessible on the second app after session sharing?

Please help on this.

**Edit 1**

Just tried Custom Authentication with Apex 23.1.1 (https://apex.oracle.com) and the Auth Function is simply returning true, no check for user existence or password matching.

Tried to login with a valid (Oracle APEX Accounts) user, loggedin. Tried an invalid/non-existing user and got the same error message i.e. `You are not authorized to view this application, either because you have not been granted access, or your account has been locked. Please...`

This suggests that Custom Auth Function is not the only thing which authenticates a user, something else is there as well which is being used for user authentication for example a table or function and that is why session sharing with Custom Authentication Scheme is not working. I may be wrong but this is my guess.

Comment: Can you confirm Workspace Sharing was set to custom in both applications, using the same cookie name?

Comment: If the application item is defined in both applications, and the scope is set to Global, you should be fine accessing the value in either application.

Comment: @Scott Yes. Session sharing Type is Custom with same cookie name in both applications.  Cookie Path and Name fields are empty

Comment: @Scott Please read **Edit**, custom auth didn't work on 23.1.1 as well.