# Apex 22.1 How to pass filters to OData Rest Service

Tags: oracle-apex

I have installed OData Rest Service plugin and defined REST Data Source against this REST source type. The .net based OData Service is returning all rows of a DB table. This table contains multiple LOVs differentiated by a Type column.

Then added a LOV using this REST Data Source, added a Popup Lov on the page and it shows all rows. So far so good.

OData filters are working via Browser as well.

`Post Processing Type` in LOV has an option of using SQL query, by this option filters/where can also be applied but the .net based OData Service will have to return all rows of the table and then APEX will filter desired results.

How can i pass OData filters from APEX so that only required data is returned from OData Service?

**Edit 1**

OData Service is working fine with filters on the browser
[image]

I have already tried setting following filters one by one in `External Filter` under `Advanced REST Data Source Attributes` on LOV edit page but none of these worked

```
$filter=CodeType eq 135
?$filter=CodeType eq 135
$filter=CodeType%20eq%20135
?$filter=CodeType%20eq%20135
filter=CodeType eq 135
```

and the error is

> l_error_pos=1, l_start_pos=1, match_pos=14
>
> Exception in "begin declare
>
> begin plg_odata_connector.fetch_web_source (p_plugin =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_plugin,p_web_source =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_web_source,p_params =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_web_source_fetch_params,p_result =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_web_source_fetch_result );end; end;": Error
> Stack: ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection ORA-06512: at
> "DEV1.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 117 ORA-06512: at
> "DEV1.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 1087 ORA-06512: at
> "DEV1.PLG_ODATA_CONNECTOR", line 839 ORA-06512: at line 4 ORA-06512:
> at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 2164 ORA-06512: at
> "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 856 Backtrace: ORA-06512: at
> "DEV1.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 117 ORA-06512: at
> "DEV1.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 1087 ORA-06512: at
> "DEV1.PLG_ODATA_CONNECTOR", line 839 ORA-06512: at line 4 ORA-06512:
> at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 2164 ORA-06512: at
> "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 856 ORA-06512: at
> "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2452 ORA-06512: at
> "DEV1.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 117 ORA-06512: at
> "DEV1.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 1087 ORA-06512: at
> "DEV1.PLG_ODATA_CONNECTOR", line 839 ORA-06512: at line 4 ORA-06512:
> at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 2164 ORA-06512: at
> "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 856 ORA-06512: at
> "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2452
>
> Error: Error in PLSQL code raised during plug-in processing.

**Edit 2**

Tried the same on Apex 23.1.1(https://apex.oracle.com), failed with different errors.

1. Imported OData plugin from
   https://github.com/oracle/apex/tree/22.2/plugins/rest-source/odata-rest-apis
2. Added https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People as
   REST Data Source
3. Added an LOV without filters against this source and all people were
   shown in a popup list
4. Added `UserName%20eq%20%27sandyosborn%27` as an `External Filter`
   which resulted errors. Partial `Full Trace` is

> module_id: 39660548962068387941 operation_id: 39660549197756387942
> url: https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService query_string:
> http_method: GET db_operation: 1 get_web_source_operation
> p_db_operation=>1,p_perform_init=>false,p_preserve_headers=>false
> PLG_ODATA_CONNECTOR.plugin_attributes Exit plugin_attributes
> PLG_ODATA_CONNECTOR. Exit get_requested_columns.
> return=FirstName,UserName Web Source Attributes Info
>
> attribute_01: People attribute_02:  attribute_03:
> option_orderby:option_select:option_search:option_client_driven_paging
> attribute_04: none attribute_05: N attribute_06: count_none Web Source
> Fetch Params Info
>
> requested_columns: [FirstName,UserName] max_rows: 101 first_row: 1
> fetch_all_rows: false fixed_page_size:  request_context:
> external_filters: UserName%20eq%20%27sandyosborn%27 Web Source Fetch
> Params Info 2
>
> order_bys: true requested_columns: true filters: true
> primary_key_values: false initial_request: true Original Query String
> is: Fetching Loop Counter (Page) = 1 ODATA Filter Format Creation
> incoming with ext Filter = UserName%20eq%20%27sandyosborn%27
> PLG_ODATA_FILTERS.odata_filter_format Total Filters Count = 0
> PLG_ODATA_FILTERS.get_sanitized_external_filter Not Sanitized External
> Filter=UserName%20eq%20%27sandyosborn%27 Exception in "begin declare
>
> begin plg_odata_connector.fetch_web_source (p_plugin =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_plugin,p_web_source =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_web_source,p_params =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_web_source_fetch_params,p_result =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_web_source_fetch_result );end; end;": Error
> Stack: ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection ORA-06512: at
> "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 117 ORA-06512: at
> "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 1087 ORA-06512: at
> "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_CONNECTOR", line 839 ORA-06512: at line 4
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 2120 ORA-06512: at
> "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 806 Backtrace: ORA-06512: at
> "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 117 ORA-06512: at
> "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 1087 ORA-06512: at
> "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_CONNECTOR", line 839 ORA-06512: at line 4
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 2120 ORA-06512: at
> "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 806 ORA-06512: at
> "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2603 ORA-06512: at
> "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 117 ORA-06512: at
> "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 1087 ORA-06512: at
> "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_CONNECTOR", line 839 ORA-06512: at line 4
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 2120 ORA-06512: at
> "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 806 ORA-06512: at
> "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2603 setting
> g_primary_language := en Add error onto error stack: Error in PLSQL
> code raised during plug-in processing. ... get_component ->
> APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEMS P1_NEW Error: Error in PLSQL code raised
> during plug-in processing.
>
> - Additional info: Contact your application administrator. Details about this incident are available via debug id "1537413071".
> - Display location: ON_ERROR_PAGE
> - Association type:
> - Item name:
> - Region id:
> - Column alias:
> - Row:
> - Model instance id:
> - Model record id:
> - Internal error: true
> - Common runtime error: false
> - APEX error code: WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN.RUN_PLSQL_ERR
> - SQL code: -6531
> - SQL error: ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_CODE_EXEC_PLSQL", line 126
>   ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2643
>   ORA-06512: at "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 117 ORA-06512: at
>   "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 1087 ORA-06512: at
>   "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_CONNECTOR", line 839 ORA-06512: at line 4
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 2120 ORA-06512: at
>   "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 806 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2603 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_CODE_EXEC_PLSQL", line 97 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_CODE_EXEC_PLSQL", line 399 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_CODE_EXEC", line 553
> - Backtrace: ORA-06512: at "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 117 ORA-06512: at "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 1087 ORA-06512:
>   at "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_CONNECTOR", line 839 ORA-06512: at line 4
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 2120 ORA-06512: at
>   "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 806 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2603 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_CODE_EXEC_PLSQL", line 126 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2643 ORA-06512: at
>   "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 117 ORA-06512: at
>   "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_FILTERS", line 1087 ORA-06512: at
>   "WKSP_TESTBRM.PLG_ODATA_CONNECTOR", line 839 ORA-06512: at line 4
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 2120 ORA-06512: at
>   "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 806 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2603 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_CODE_EXEC_PLSQL", line 97 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_CODE_EXEC_PLSQL", line 399 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_CODE~
> - Statement: begin declare
>
> begin plg_odata_connector.fetch_web_source (p_plugin =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_plugin,p_web_source =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_web_source,p_params =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_web_source_fetch_params,p_result =>
> wwv_flow_plugin_api.g_web_source_fetch_result );end; end;
>
> - Component: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEMS P1_NEW (35162212600458618115) ...Show Error on Error Page ......Performing rollback do_rollback
>   reset p_keep_sticky_headers=>true add_header
>   p_key=>Apex-Error-Code,p_name=>Apex-Error-Code,p_value=>WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN.RUN_PLSQL_ERR,p_overwrite=>true,p_is_sticky=>true
>   add_header p_key=>Apex-Error,p_name=>Apex-Error,p_value=>Error in
>   PLSQL code raised during plug-in
>   processing.,p_overwrite=>true,p_is_sticky=>true write_headers
>   p_close_header_section=>true ... no header that is known to sys.htp -
>   emit Content-Type text/html ... get_component ->
>   APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEMS P1_NEW Exception in "P1_NEW": Error Stack:
>   ORA-20987: APEX - Error in PLSQL code raised during plug-in
>   processing. - Contact your application administrator. Details about
>   this incident are available via debug id "1537413071". ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2322 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2238 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1075 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1523 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 2193 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 4095 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 4140 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2226 Backtrace: ORA-06512:
>   at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2322 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2238 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1075 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1523 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 2193 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 4095 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 4140 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2226 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2602 ... get_component ->
>   APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEMS P1_NEW Exception in "P1_NEW": Error Stack:
>   ORA-20987: APEX - Error in PLSQL code raised during plug-in
>   processing. - Contact your application administrator. Details about
>   this incident are available via debug id "1537413071". ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2636 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2322 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2238 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1075 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1523 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 2193 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 4095 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 4140 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2226 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2602 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2653 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", line 838 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", line 1144 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_LOV", line 1745 Backtrace: ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2636 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2322 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2238 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1075 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1523 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 2193 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 4095 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 4140 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2226 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2602 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_WEB_SRC", line 2653 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", line 838 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", line 1144 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_LOV", line 1745 ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_NATIVE_ITEM", line 3573 close_context
>   context_type=>1 JSON for internal error already written
>   stop_apex_engine Final commit do_commit

Comment: Have a look into the Advanced REST Data Source Attributes section on the Shared LOV edit page. You can enter OData filter syntax into the External Filter field, which the Plug-In should pick up and send to the OData Server. 

Does that work?

Comment: @Carsten Already tried, didn't work. Question updated with error.

Comment: @Carsten Please check **Edit 2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. This is a bug in the filter code of the OData Plug-In. I will fix this as soon as possible, and provide an updated version of the app and the plug-in.

If you don't want to wait for that, you can fix the issue in the PLG_ODATA_FILTERS PL/SQL package. Simply wrap the loop in line 95 into an IF block to check whether variable is NOT NULL.

```
:
    -- Loop to replace the &items. with the sanitized values and return the String
    if l_items_sanitized is not null then
        for i in 1 .. l_items_sanitized.count loop
        :
        end loop; 
    end if;
:
```

After that, *only* provide the actual filter (`CodeType eq 135`), and not the $filter URL parameter, which is constructed by the Plug-In.

Comment: It worked. Any suggestion on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76669591/apex-22-1-session-sharing-with-custom-authentication-scheme

Comment: I have now updated the code on github.com/oracle/apex as well. If you download the plug-in anew, you'll get the fixed version.

Comment: Thanks, I have already applied your solution and it is working. Now looking for some suggestions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76669591/apex-22-1-session-sharing-with-custom-authentication-scheme

Comment: How to pass Application Item as a filter e.g. `(CodeType eq :App_Item)`? App Item as where clause in `Post Processing SQL Query` is also not resolving the item to its value. I am unable to find any help in the documentation.

Comment: Use substitution syntax ... &ITEM. However, this is only allowed within a string literal (e.g. '&PX_NAME.'); and the Plug-In validates this.

Comment: This is resulting in a string value while the data/column type is numeric. `Body: {"error":{"code":"","message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. ')' or operator expected at position 35 in '(CodeType eq 128 and CodeNumb eq ''1'')'."}` .  This should have been `(CodeType eq 128 and CodeNumb eq 1)`

Comment: Yeah - that is a known limitation. Item substutitions are only allowed within (quoted) string literals.

Comment: This limitation is making the plugin unusable as all columns/fields are not required to be string, numeric and date are very common types.

Comment: I am infact trying to use OData to overcome the limitation of using APEX with Oracle only.  I assume Customer data, apart from apex application, can reside on any database if I publish OData based REST service. Am i going in right direction?

Comment: Well, _item substitutions_ (&PX_ITEM) in the *External Filters* attribute are not supported outside of a string, as a plain substitution would allow the end user to "break out" of the developer provided query expression. When you look at Interactive Report filters, the APEX_EXEC PL/SQL package or other areas where filters are used, all numeric filtering is supported without issues. The page item substitution (&PX_ITEM.) is the critical thing here.

Comment: Here is an alternative approach to pass an additional (dynamic) filters to an OData REST Source (e.g. for an LOV): Craft a table function, use APEX_EXEC.OPEN_REST_SOURCE_QUERY, and pass filter records in using the P_FILTER argument. Then receive the results and pipe rows back. That will achieve what you want, without having to use Page Item Substitutions. See doc for an example: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aeapi/OPEN_REST_SOURCE_QUERY-Function.html#GUID-F09E0A46-8282-4917-8C3B-94910F9DD919

Comment: This may work for `GET` but what about `PUT/POST/DELETE`? Do i have to create separate functions for each and how this would work for `FORM`?

Comment: The Plug-In currently only supports "read" operations, i.e. a Form DML process will not work with the plug-in. Such read/write support is on our roadmap, but I have no ETA yet ...

Comment: This is a bad news for me :)

Comment: I have managed to overcome the `string` limitation on server side. However, I noticed that this OData source does not work well with a Popup LOV. I have 162 items in my LOV, after loading 80 items the Popup LOV stucks with loading status. And on server side i keep getting `Get` request with same filters. Seems like a combined issue of Popup LOV and OData source because Popup LOV works well with direct table and Select List works with OData source.

Comment: can the popup LOV issue be reproduced in the Sample App which comes with the Plug-In ...? Would like to have a closer look into this.

Comment: It is working in Sample App with Sample-Northwind-Orders. I am using Web API on .NET 7 with OData V8. Didn't find any public service on this platform/tech.

Comment: Hmmm … can you turn on debug at LEVEL9, then open the Popup LOV to reproduce the issue? In the LEVEL9 output we might see the reason for the loading being stuck.

Comment: I received 392 requests on the server which stopped on page refresh. Any hint to identify 'stuck' condition as there is only 1 entry in the log of my odata service `making GET request to http://192.168.0.110:5164/odata/main/v1/CodeListOData?$select=...`

Comment: Browser's Console is showing multiple entries like `Server debug log message written: View Identifier = 9739, Level = 3. http://192.168.0.75:8080/ords/f?p=4000:939:6110109571506::NO:939:P939_PAGE_VIEW_ID:9739#
debug.js?v=23.1.0:241 Model: PopupLov_7_P7_NEW_m. add data merge:  100 undefined true
debug.js?v=23.1.0:241 Model: PopupLov_7_P7_NEW_m. forEachInPage fetching more data starting at:  100
debug.js?v=23.1.0:258  Server debug log message written: View Identifier = 9740, Level = 3. http://192.168.0.75:8080/ords/f?p=4000:939:6110109571506::NO:939:P939_PAGE_VIEW_ID:9740#
debug.js?v=...`

Comment: I would need to see the full debug output (Debug > View Debug): I'm not sure whether you can upload here. If not, feel free to send by email (Oracle scheme is firstname<dot>lastname<at>oracle<dot>com).

Comment: email sent. Subject is `StackOverflow Question: Apex 22.1 How to pass filters to OData Rest Service`

Comment: Thanks. From the debug log, the pagination behavior appears a bit odd. I don't see $skip and $top query parameters; did you enable pagination? And what does your REST API expect here?

Comment: My mistake. `Source supports client-driven pagination` was not checked for the REST Data Source. Now server receives two requests for 161 records; Skip=0, Top=101 and Skip=100, Top=101. However the Popup LOV shows only 100 records. Debug info emailed to you.

Comment: hmmm ... the debug contains the second request which returned 62 rows back to APEX (the first request is probably within another debug output). When you're saying, the Popup LOV shows only 100 rows, you clicked the "Load More" multiple times, but after 100 rows, that button was disabled and you could not get more rows ... is that assumption correct?

Comment: "Load More" button remianed enabled (getting the focus, border color turned blue) but nothing happened on click, no wait clock appeared.

Comment: hmmm ... is there _any_ way to provide a test case for this? E.g. on the apex.oracle.com public instance ...?